# Powershell continua con el borrado incluso si la variable es incorrecta

Tags: powershell

Buenas a todos.

Tengo un problemilla en mi script de Powershell en el cual estoy realizando un borrado del contenido de un directorio. El path de dicho directorio se almacena en una variable y se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
Write-Host "* Vaciando '$RutaTempFicheros'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Try { Remove-Item -Path $RutaTempFicheros* -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop }
Catch { ManejarErrores -codigo 13 }
```

El problema viene cuando haciendo pruebas (vaciando la variable, colocando otra nueva sin valor, etc) y pensando que daría error, Powershell sigue con el borrado, pero en este caso vacía el directorio en el que se encuentra, que en este caso es el directorio donde se almacena el script.

¿Alguna idea de porqué esto es así o de cómo realizarlo para evitar este problema?

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en como se encuentra definido el valor del parámetro "Path", ya que se encuentra lo siguiente:

```
$RutaTempFicheros*
```

De lo anterior toma la variable **$RutaTempFicheros** y el símbolo * que funciona como un wildcard. Por ello te borra los ítems de tu ubicación.
El * indica que borre en el path que actualmente se encuentra ubicado al momento de ejecutar.

Saludos,

Victor Silva

Comment: Entiendo ¿entonces de qué forma podría vaciar el directorio o al menos evitar que borre del directorio actual? He pensado en hacer una función a parte que controle esto, lo cual resolvería el problema, aunque desearía no tener que escribir una función independentiente, preferiría realizarlo enteramente con lo que powershell me provee directamente.

Comment: Para que no borre el directorio actual (en donde estás ubicado) simplemente quitá el asterisco (*) de la variable $RutaTempFicheros. Al quitar ese símbolo, el script debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he caido en eso y lo he probado, funciona sin problema.